# How/Where to import ngVue in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, vue.js

We recently decided our transition of migrating our biggest project from `AngularJS` to `Vue`, but for now we are just giving it a try one by one. We would like to use `Vue component` in `Angular page`.

The matter we face is this error :

> Module 'ngVue' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

We have followed the guide which https://github.com/ngVue/ngVue has shown, but we keep facing this issue.

[image]

Here is the code we tried

notice.module.js

```js
(function () {
  "use strict";

  angular.module("app.notice", ["ngVue"]).config(config);

  /** @ngInject */
  function config($stateProvider) {
    // State
    ....
  }
})();
```

and I have no idea where to import ngVue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing an `require 'ngVue';` in your `notice.module.js` file